# android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError setX on Drag Drop event

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setX

I am getting this error when I try to run my application on device. On Emulator it works fine.. I am applying drag drop event on ImageView.

Here is my code

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent){  
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         v.setX(motionEvent.getRawX());
     v.setY(motionEvent.getRawY());

     break;

     default:
     break;
 }
 return true; 
}
```

Please Help out
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

View.setX() since API level 11 (Honeycomb Android 3.0.x) check your device Android version.

Comment: Is there any other way to do drag and drop ImageViews for other API level devices?